# How do I make an 80% width div horizontally scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I have a seat map that may contain 20 seats besides each other or 200. I don't know the width so I'd like to make it 80% wide and horizontally scrollable, no matter how wide it is.

I already tried to set it as:

```
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

or:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

but neither is working.

Here's a fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywzb365t/

The div I need horizontally scrollable is `#seat-map`.

Resize it horizontally to see the problem I have. If I don't make it 100% wide and horizontally scrollable, it will mix up the seat rows.

I am pretty sure it's just a simple thing but I can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap it in an 80% wide container and set the overflow to scroll?

Comment: has mostly to do with your floats

Comment: @DBS I will give that a try.

Comment: @zgood Will also try, thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: Unfortunately removing the float:left; didn't work :(

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the float of the 'div.seatCharts-cell' ? I can't remove that because that's the way it works.

Comment: Did you try overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;?

Comment: Yep, on pretty much every container. Even a wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that `seatCharts-row` is equal to the content and then `seatCharts-container` have `overflow-x:auto`

I wrote a little fix here that will change `seatCharts-row` width.

Place this code at the bottom of `$(document).ready(function()`

```
  $(".seatCharts-container").css({ overflow:"hidden",  "overflow-x" :"auto" })

  $(".seatCharts-container > .seatCharts-row").each(function(){
   var width =($(this).children().length * $(this).children().first().outerWidth(true))
   $(this).width(width)      
  })
```

Comment: Getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error. I added semicolons but still seems wrong?

Comment: Was my bad, yep. Works perfectly. Thanks for saving my night! :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
div.seatCharts-cell {
  float: left;
}
```

to

```
div.seatCharts-cell {
  display: inline;
}
```

makes it scroll horizontally but im not sure if this is the desired output.  Alen might have a better answer

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the width of `.container` to the desired 80%, and then changed the `.seatCharts-row` width to `max-content`.

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3xq92fk/). Is this what you're looking for?